# Is it possible with stack to avoid unregistering and re-compiling most (if not all) of the dependencies when switching between `--profile` on and off?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

It takes several hours to recompile about 100 dependencies if I accidentally let stack unregister them when switching between `--profile` on and off.

I don't mean the initial building of the packages with both, but subsequent builds.

Currently I try to work around by having different copies of `.stack-work`. I'm trying to use hardlinks too via `cp -al`. But I hope stack could also just not throw away hours worth of compiled dependencies so willingly without so much as a warning. Or even better, if it kept both without unregistering.

I have Version 1.4.1, Git revision 3d29b8c68a x86_64 hpack-0.17.0

Comment: This may be a regression in Stack. I'd recommend first upgrading to the latest version with stack upgrade, and if the problem persists, reporting an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MichaelSnoyman, I hope to do what you suggest in the coming days.